# Using HashMaps in spinners android studio

Tags: android, hashmap, android-spinner

I am using dynamic and static spinner.
This is my code, how can I implement a `HashMap` to show what the user selects (values)?

```
public class DatosAutoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner sp_marca, sp_modelo, sp_colores;

    private TextView tvMarca, tvModelo, tvColor, tvPlacas;
    private Button btn_enviarDatos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos_auto);


        sp_marca = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_marca);
        sp_modelo = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_modelo);
        sp_colores = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_colores);


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.array_marcas,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_marca.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp_marca.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterColor = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.array_colores,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterColor.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_colores.setAdapter(adapterColor);
        sp_colores.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        int[] marcas = {R.array.array_chevrolet, R.array.array_ford, R.array.array_honda,
                R.array.array_nissan,R.array.array_renault, R.array.array_toyota,
                R.array.array_volkswagen};

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                marcas[position],
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_modelo.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        btn_enviarDatos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_enviarDatos);

        btn_enviarDatos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent siguiente = new Intent(DatosAutoActivity.this, VerificacionDatosActivity.class);
                    startActivity(siguiente);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass `HashMap` data to Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Hashmap hope this will help you.**

**Value for spinner**

```
String[] spinnerArray = new String[array.size()];
HashMap<Integer,String> spinnerMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
   spinnerMap.put(i,array.get(i));
   spinnerArray[i] = array.get(i);
}
```

**Set value to spinner**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Get value from spinner**

```
String name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String id = spinnerMap.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:                                    
       HashMap<String, String> datos = new HashMap<>();
        datos.put("Chevrolet","Chevy");

Comment: For example, I have these values: '<string-array name="array_marcas">
        <item>Chevrolet</item>
        <item>Ford</item>
        <item>Honda</item>
        <item>Nissan</item>
        <item>Renault</item>
        <item>Toyota</item>
        <item>Volkswagen</item>
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="array_chevrolet">
        <item>Chevy</item>
        <item>Spark</item>
        <item>Aveo</item>
        <item>Malibú</item>
    </string-array>